# Differences between cube measures and mdx measures

Tags: mdx, mdx-query

is there a difference between a native cube measure (for example Measure1) and this mdx measure :
`Measure2=[Measures].[Measure1]` ?

Because when I use these measures together I dont get any results, and when I use them one by one I get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

So the Cube Measures are present at the time of cube processing where the "MDX measures"(correct name is calculations) are determined at the query time. You should try to use the Cube measures where ever possible.
Secondly they can be easily used together.

Comment: Nomally if I define a calculation like Measure1 = [Measures].[CubeMeasure] then Measure1 and [CubeMeasure]  should work exactly the same, no ? and it's not what I get.

Comment: Yes that is how it should work. Share the query or screen shots.